# Django-celery-beat：dynamically change PeriodicTask in MySQL, but not working

Tags: rabbitmq, django-celery-beat

I want use Django + Celery + RabbitMQ + django-celery-beat to build some timed task, and I can update the task data(interval or enabled) at django_celery_beat.models.PeriodicTask, but when I update these data, celery beat won't work every time.

I hope I can use an API to update tasks dynamically, and celery beat can catch these updated data, and sent it to RabbitMQ queues

I'm using:

```
Python 3.6.2
Django 2.1.4
celery 4.4.7
django-celery-beat 1.6.0
RabbitMQ 3.5.7
```

Celery Setup:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "amqp://myuser:mypassword@x.x.x.x:5672/myvhost"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "rpc://"
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = False
DJANGO_CELERY_BEAT_TZ_AWARE = False
CELERY_TIMEZONE = TIME_ZONE
```

Tasks module in Django:

```
class AlertTasks(BaseModel):
    interval = models.IntegerField(default=-1)
    enable = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    task = models.ForeignKey(PeriodicTask, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

code for update Tasks:

```
def update_alert_tasks(task_id, enable, interval):
    with transaction.atomic():
        task = AlertTasks.objects.select_for_update().filter(id=task_id).first()
        if enable:
            if task.interval != -1:
                task.task.enabled = enable
                task.task.save()
            task.enable = enable
        if (
            interval
            and task.interval != -1
            and interval > 0
            and interval != task.interval
        ):
            task.interval = interval
            old_schedule = task.task.interval
            schedule, _ = IntervalSchedule.objects.get_or_create(
                every=interval, period=strategy.interval_type
            )
            task.task.interval = schedule
            task.task.save()
            if not PeriodicTask.objects.filter(interval=old_schedule).exists():
                old_schedule.delete()
        task.save()
    return task.id
```